# Display duration and remaining time in jPlayer playlist

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm wondering is it possible to show duration and remaining time in jPlayer playlist?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but you could also display manually any info you'd like to any song in the playlist like I did:

1.Open the jplayer.playlist.js and right before `listItem += "</div></li>";` add your custom html element ( which will be visible later on each song ) e.g:

```
listItem += "<div class='custom-duration'>" + media.customduration + "</div>";
```

2.Inside your jPlayerPlaylist js code , add a new line on on each song which will define your customduration element and it will look like so:

```
{
      title:"Cro Magnon Man",
      mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
      customduration: "3:22"
    },
```

This method is useful if for example you will type the link to a 30 sec song but inside that custom field it will show the full duration ( the one that you typed for each song). And this way the actual duration of that preview will not interfere with the info you typed.